# Hide or autohide top bar

Tags: 2.2-froyo, notification-bar, user-interface

Is it possible to hide or autohide the top bar which is still present on the top of Android screen? My version of Android is 2.2.

The top bar is distracting for me while reading. I'm using `Aldiko`, `ezPDF Reader`, `Infinity` for reading. Most **distracting** is the **wifi icon** which is changing when something happens with the connection.

And the top bar is **using space** on a **small display** which can be better utilized (e.g. in `Teamviewer`)

Some **video players** can hide the top bar (default `Video player`) and some can't (`Act1 Video player` - which I like more but don't use because of the top bar).

Thank you.

Comment: Certain apps have fullscreen mode.  Those that don't probably won't be able to take advantage of the extra space if you were to hide it?  I'm not sure.

Comment: `Infinity` browser has fullscreen mode but the top bar is still there.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the top bar if you use a different launcher like @CustomiZer stated, but it will **Only** hide it when you are on the home screen. When you open apps, if they are not Full Screen apps, the top bar will still be present.

This is part of "core" android, and it is not something that can be changed, currently, via a setting or 3rd party application.

Comment: I edited the question. The top bar is present even in fullscreen (see `Infinity` browser).

Comment: My answer is still the same, the app doesn't seem to actually use "full screen mode" if the top bar is still there.

Comment: OK, it seems this is the feature of individual applications. Is there a proof that application A can't change this property in application B? You probably have this information from somewhere. Could you please cite this source?

Comment: Its not a feature of an application, it is a feature of the Core System. it allows the application to cover it, if the application specifies that it is a full screen activity.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not possible with the default home screen. 
This is possible with alternative home replacement like [GO Launcher EX](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&feature=search_result), [LauncherPro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fede.launcher&feature=search_result), [ADW Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher&feature=search_result), etc. Some of these allow hiding of the top notification bar in their respective settings with specific swipe actions.

Comment: The top bar is distracting for me while reading. I'm using `Aldiko`, `ezPDF Reader`, `Infinity` for reading. Most distracting is the wi-fi icon which is changing when something happens with the connection. And the top bar is using space on a small display which can be better utilized (e.g. in `Teamviewer`)

Comment: I don't think  you can do it when opening other apps (unless you mod the ROM I guess)